# Couldn't save the theme change to users. where could be the error?

Tags: javascript

Couldn't save the theme change to users. where could be the issue?

```
const toggleswitch = document.querySelector('.checkbox');
const currentTheme = localStorage.getItem('themesw') ? localStorage.getItem('themesw') : null;
if (currentTheme == 'light') {

    toggleswitch.checked = true;
    document.querySelectorAll('.night-mode-available').forEach(ele => {
        ele.classList.toggle('night');
    })

}
else {
    toggleswitch.checked = false;
}
```

I am able switch theme by using below code.

```
document.querySelector('.checkbox').addEventListener('change', () => {
    document.querySelectorAll('.night-mode-available').forEach(ele => {
        ele.classList.toggle('night');
    })
});
```

It seems like the saving part and  loading part is having some slight errors.

```
if (toggleswitch.checked) {
    localStorage.setItem('themesw', 'light');
}
else {
    localStorage.setItem('themesw', 'dark');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't you load it from storage and 'check' the box, which then triggers your event listener and swaps the theme back?

Comment: Exactly. when page refresh it going back to default theme.

Comment: So why not change `if (currentTheme == 'light') {` to do JUST `toggleswitch.checked = true;`. Then the eventlistener would update the theme, no?

Comment: No. the issue is the toggle change not getting saved. on refresh page, it going back to default mode.